# jquery.on("show.bs.modal", m.redraw) corrupts the dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-modal, mithril.js

I'm trying to use Twitter Bootstrap with Mithril. Usually redrawing a dialog with Bootstrap wrapped with Mithril works, but redrawing in a handler for `"show.bs.modal"` event hides the dialog leaving the backdrop. It doesn't solve even with `setTimeout`, which should provide a different execution context. Why and how can I fix it?

Here is a simple PoC.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/173210/8c84966696276f1bfa3e298edb53da2b

Rawgit (working demo): https://rawgit.com/173210/8c84966696276f1bfa3e298edb53da2b/raw/34b0ac625962ee830d63829107eeb0473c735375/poc.html

In short, this doesn't work.

```
jquery.on("shown.bs.modal", () => setTimeout(m.redraw, 2000));
```

Answer (score 0):

`m.redraw` only works for [components](http://mithril.js.org/components.html) that have been mounted with [`m.mount`](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.mount.html) or [`m.route`](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.route.html).

I made a few changes to your code: 
https://jsbin.com/wegeyi/edit?js,output

- If we put your virtual DOM code in a component view, and change `m.render` to `m.mount`, we can replace `f` with `m.redraw`.
- I added a draw counter to indicate that the code is re-executing as expected.
- DOM attributes that aren't functions, like `className`, `type`, etc can be expressed in the `m()` [selector argument](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.html#signature)

Comment: Thanks, I applied some changes to the PoC. However it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I thought the issue was that you couldn't make `setTimeout( m.redraw )` work. If you look at [the demo I put up](https://jsbin.com/wegeyi/edit?js,output), you can see that the number increases after 2 seconds (and once every time you click the button. What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: `m.render` overwrites `className`, which was altered by `$(element).modal("show")`, so you must prevent that. You have two options:

1. Get the `className` after `$(element).modal("show")` and reflect it to the model.
2. Set `className` in `config` when `initialized` is false.

I choose 2. It looks like the following:

```
m("div", {
  config(element, initialized) {
    if (!initialized) {
      element.className = "modal fade";
      $(element)
        .on("shown.bs.modal", () => setTimeout(m.redraw, 2000))
        .modal("show");
    }
  }
}, conentOfTheModalDialog);
```